# Python "help()" displays using "more" instead of "less" in Anaconda Prompt

Tags: python, python-interactive

I am using Anaconda Prompt (using Windows 10) at my work environment and when I type `help(str)`, it displays the help text using `more` and I can only navigate the message down page by page.

However at my home Linux environment, `help(str)` displays the text using `less` and I can freely move up/down and even search with `/`.

How can I change the behavior on my work environment so it is easier to navigate the help text? I am not familiar with Windows.

Thank you very much.

Comment: silly q: do you have `less` in your work anaconda env?

Comment: I tried `less` on a file, it didn't work. But `more` works. So the problem is that Windows doesn't have `less`?

Comment: Windows doesn't have `less`. Not built-in, anyway.

Comment: @BoarGules, are you saying there is no way to achieve that? I can live with that if it is not possible.

Comment: there are a few approaches: run in git bash prompt (easiest), install coreutils, install cygwin